# File is not readable after file.setReadable(true)

Tags: java, io

I try to read the file and get FileNotFoundExeption.

```
File file = new File("News.out");
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
try{
    in.readObject();
}
```

I check, that the file really exists in the directory and check "readable" property of the file.

Then I added programmatical setting of "readable" and "writable" properties

```
    file.setReadable(true);
    file.setWritable(true);
    System.out.println(file.canRead());
    System.out.println(file.canWrite());
```

And got in logs false, false.

What may be the reason of this?

**EDIT:**

I tried JSR 203 and use this code:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filename);
try(
    final InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(path);
) {
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    newsStorage.setEntities((ArrayList<News>) objectInputStream.readObject());
} catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
    createFile(path, filename);
    handleException(e);
}
```

And createFile() method:

```
private void createFile(Path path, String string) {
    try {
        Files.newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

File was not created.

Do I understand correctly, that

```
Files.newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

should create a file?

Comment: How do you run your application?

Comment: @Ortomala Lokni It is Eclipse RCP application, I run it from Eclipse IDE using Run Configuration.

Comment: Print `System.getProperty("user.dir"))` and check if `News.out` is inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and drop `File`. Use JSR 203 instead.

Try and use:

```
try (
    final InputStream in = Files.newInputStream("News.out");
) {
    // work with "in" here
}
```

If you can't perform the opening then you will at least have an exception telling you what exactly is wrong, something `File` has never been able to do.

After that, if you want to set permissions on the file, you can also do so with JSR 203 but that depends on the capabilities of the underlying filesystem. If your filesystem is POSIX compatible then you may use [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setPosixFilePermissions-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-) for instance. But it also may be that you cannot modify the permissions of the file either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use JSR 203, but file was not created and I got NoSuchFileException. I updated the initial post. Could you please say, did I do everything right?

Comment: If the file was not created then it means that a directory of the path didn't exist. For instance, if you try and create `a/b/c` but directory `a/b` does not exist, then you will get that exception. You need to create directory `a/b` first.